# generate random sequence and plot in R

Tags: r

I would like to generate a random sequence composed of 3000 points, which follows the normal distribution. The mean is c and the standard deviation is d. But I would like these 3000 points lies in the range of [a,b].

Can you tell me how to do it in R?

If I would like to plot this sequence, if Y-axis uses the generated 3000 points, then how should I generate the points corresponding to X-axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using standard R functions like this:

```
c <- 1
d <- 2

a <- -2
b <- 3.5

ll <- pnorm(a, c, d)
ul <- pnorm(b, c, d)

x <- qnorm( runif(3000, ll, ul), c, d )
hist(x)
range(x)
mean(x)
sd(x)
plot(x, type='l')
```

The pnorm function is used to find the limits to use for  the uniform distriution, data is then generated from a uniform and then transformed back to the normal.

This is even simpler using the distr package:

```
library(distr)

N <- Norm(c,d)
N2 <- Truncate(N, lower=a, upper=b)

plot(N2)
x <- r(N2)(3000)
hist(x)
range(x)
mean(x)
sd(x)
plot(x, type='l')
```

Note that in both cases the mean is not c and the sd is not d.  If you want the mean and sd of the resulting truncated data to be c and d, then you need the parent distribution (before truncating) to have different values (higher sd, mean depends on the truncating values), finding those values would be a good homework problem for a math/stat theory course.  If that is what you really need then add a comment or edit the question to say so specifically.

If you want to generate the data from the untruncated normal, but only plot the data within the range [a,b] then just use the ylim argument to plot:

```
plot( rnorm(3000, c, d), ylim=c(a,b) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Generating a random sequence of numbers from any probability distribution is very easy in R. To do this for the normal distribution specifically

```
c = 1
d = 2
x <- rnorm(3000, c, d)
```

Clipping the values in `x` so that they're only within a given range is kind of a strange thing to want to do with a sample from the normal distribution. Maybe what you really want to do is sample a uniform distribution.

```
a = 0
b = 3
x2 <- runif(3000, a, b)
```

As for how the plot the distribution, I'm not sure I follow your question. You can plot a density estimate for the sample with this code

```
plot(density(x))
```

But, if you want to plot this data as a scatter plot of some sort, you actually need to generate a second sample of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> If I would like to plot this sequence, if Y-axis uses the generated 3000 points, then how should I generate the points corresponding to X-axis.

If you just generate your points, like JoFrhwld said with

```
y <- rnorm(3000, 1, 2)
```

Then

```
plot(y)
```

Will automatically plot them using the array indices as x axis

Answer (score 0):

```
a = -2; b = 3
plot(dnorm, xlim = c(a, b))
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP asked for. He wants 3000 points following the normal distribution, so `rnorm` is the way to go

Comment: it's a poorly formed questions... I took a guess.  If it was just really plotting the random values on the y-axis, as part of it suggests, what the heck is the x-axis limit request?  It makes no sense.  My guess is that the random values are requested to generate a density function as did @joFrhwld and @Joris Mays.  This is the right way to generate a density function.